# How do you untoggle hiding toolbars and panels in Komodo IDE?

Tags: komodo, komodo-ide

I am using Komodo 10. The tutorial gave me the following:

[image]

I clicked on the "eye" icon and things went away. I see no way to get them to come back, that is "to toggle". This is what I see after clicking the "eye icon":

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first off I'd really recommend posting this on the [Komodo Forums](http://community.komodoide.com/), that's what they're for! ;)

If you go to the next step in the tutorial it explains how to toggle everything back. In short, hit the ALT key, then go to View > Toggle Focus Mode.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe it's come to where the default is to hide the menu bar.

Comment: Komodo so not user friendly !!